# Help for solving this sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series

I couldn't solve the following sequence and couldn't even see any pattern:

[image: Sequence]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check the OEIS. In particular, we have: $prime(n) -2n$ as seen [here](http://oeis.org/A179437).

Comment: Then actually it's -(2n-prime(n)) . Thank you.

Comment: @xecute Right; great. The OEIS is generally a good first place to check whenever you have a sequence. . .